# Plotting multiseries data with restricted range in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, categorical-data

For reference, this is what my data looks like:

```
   ID              ABCA2       ABCA3      ABCA5
1  A1         0.04146778 -0.10448552  0.1917801
2  A2         0.10223063  0.03305589  0.1465377
3  A3        -0.12581648  0.09651400 -0.1105879
```

I'm a little lost because I'm trying to get a categorical scatterplot (categories are IDs like A1, etc.) with a bounded [0,1] range for the y-axis. Something that looks like this, basically. How do I do this with R functions like ggplot2, etc? I have 769 categories, and 18000 datapoints for each

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to plot all of the points, regardless of whether they fall under `ABCA2`, `ABCA3`, `ABCA5` etc.

Say your data frame is called `df` and there are no other variables besides `ID` and those of the form `ABCA_`. Then you can gather all of those `ABCA_` subgroups into one column:

```
tidyr::gather(df, key = "ABCA_group", value = "value", -ID)

#   ID   ABCA_group       value
# 1 A1        ABCA2  0.04146778
# 2 A2        ABCA2  0.10223063
# 3 A3        ABCA2 -0.12581648
# 4 A1        ABCA3 -0.10448552
# 5 A2        ABCA3  0.03305589
# 6 A3        ABCA3  0.09651400
# 7 A1        ABCA5  0.19178010
# 8 A2        ABCA5  0.14653770
# 9 A3        ABCA5 -0.11058790
```

Now we can pipe this into `ggplot` to get a categorical scatterplot (with a little horizontal jitter), and limit the y-axis to [0, 1] (which will remove values like -0.12581648). Make sure to `library(dplyr)` beforehand to get the pipe operator `%>%`.

```
tidyr::gather(df, key = "ABCA_group", value = "value", -ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = value)) +
    geom_jitter(color = "red", width = 0.05) +
    ylim(c(0, 1))

# Warning message:
# Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image: Categorical Scatterplot]

I'm assuming you won't be plotting all 769 categories on the x-axis at the same time, so you can select only a subset of those by adding an extra filtering step between `tidyr::gather` and `ggplot`:

```
tidyr::gather(...) %>%
   dplyr::filter(ID %in% c("A1", "A2")) %>%
   ggplot(...)
```